# How to get user story points using pyral?

Tags: python, pyral

I am trying to modify the statecounts.py from pyral examples to pull all the defined/accepted/in progress/completed stories point for each release.  I am keep getting query exception error.  Is there anything that I have missed?

```
state = 'ScheduleState'
state_values = rally.getAllowedValues('HierarchicalRequirement', state)
output = []
for rel in sorted(release_names):
    for state_value in sorted(state_values):
        response = rally.get(artifact_type, fetch="FormattedID", query='(Release.Name= %s ) AND %s = %s' % (rel, state, state_value),
                                projectScopeUp=False, projectScopeDown=False)
        output.append("%20s : %16s : %5d" % (rel, state, state_value, response.resultCount))
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are ANDing multiple terms it's easiest to create a list of terms like so:

```
query=['Release.Name = %s' % (rel), '%s = %s' % (state, state_value)]
```

Also, whitespace matters. You were missing a space before the first =.